# How do I find out more information about an unknown data type in Visual Basic for Applications?

Tags: vba, excel

I was provided an Excel document by a third party with macros and I am supposed to extend their functionality.

As I am reviewing the third party code, I came across some weird data types:

```
IUtlPropertySet2
CStandardPropertySet2
```

They are being used like so:

```
Dim myDataType as IUtlPropertySet2
...
Set myDataType = new CStandardPropertySet2
```

I have searched all of their files for these data types but could not find them anywhere.

Could someone shed some light on what these data types could be?

Comment: Does the code compile? If so, did you check for Class Modules? Did you check for any unusual references?

Comment: @DanielCook, The code compiles and I checked all available files. Nothing. :(

Comment: If you have thouroughly checked the code, then you need to check the project references.

Comment: @Beaner, Hi Beaner, how do I check project references? I am using Excel 2003

Comment: @czchlong Alt+F11 to open VBA Editor, open menu - Tools | References...

Comment: Should this be tagged VBA and/or Excel instead? I see no VB6 question here.

Comment: @BobRiemersma Agreed -- have suggested an edit for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [VBA Object Browser](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080557817.aspx) to find out what they are.

1. Open your Excel spreadsheet.
2. Press Alt+F11 to open the VBA environment.
3. Press F2 to open the Object Browser window.
4. Type the name of the data type into the search box and click the binoculars icon.
5. Use the search results to find out more information.